# Sulla differenza fra ‘Sì, all'inizio inizio.’ ‘Sì, all'inizio.’ e ‘Sì, ma solo all'inizio.’

Tags: grammar

Uno mi ha detto

> ... all'inizio i sindacati difendevano realmente i diritti dei lavoratori ...

e io ho risposto

> Sì, all'inizio inizio.

Che differenza c'è fra

> Sì, all'inizio inizio.
>
> Sì, all'inizio.
>
> Sì, ma solo all'inizio.

che appaiono alternative possibili nel contesto illustrato?

Comment: *inizio inizio* è una forma tipicamente del parlato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una nota sulla prima variante: in generale la [reduplicazione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplicazione)  è un procedimento usato nel linguaggio colloquiale soprattutto infantile (ma non solo), per intensificare  il grado di aggettivi (*piccolo piccolo*) e avverbi (*bene bene*), l'azione di verbi (*cammina cammina, senti senti*),
e  il significato di nomi,  come in questo caso. *Sono nato a Milano Milano*: dentro le mura spagnole; *vorrei un caffè caffè*: un vero caffè. *All'inizio inizio*: proprio all'inizio, nella primissima fase iniziale.

Per il resto le differenze fra le tre varianti mi sembrano più un fatto di logica che di lingua (*solo all'inizio*: dopo non più).

Nel contesto citato  tutte e tre  le risposte suonano come una parziale concessione all'affermazione fatta dall'interlocutore, ma anche un suo ridimensionamento.

Answer (score 4):

Tutte e tre le forme sottolineano come soltanto all'inizio i sindacati abbiano aiutato i lavoratori, ma con alcune differenze.

- "Inizio inizio" è una forma per sottolineare il concetto (ripetendolo) usata non spesso nell'italiano parlato, e non è un'espressione formale. Non si trova se non in dialoghi tra amici...
- Tra la seconda e la terza scelta ci sono poche differenze. Probabilmente la terza, con l'uso del "ma", riesce a dare più enfasi e a sottolineare ancora di più il concetto